# how to set a controller dynamically to a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dynamic-programming, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to set a controller dynamically to directive

```
<child-directive ctrl='BankController' ctrl-as='Bankctrl' child-url='src/accounts/finance/templates/bank/bank.tpl.html'></child-directive>
```

---

```
let module ='abc.core.child';


class ChildDirective{
    constructor() {
        var ctrl='';
        var ctrlAs='';
        var url=''
        this.link= function(scope, element, attrs) {
           console.log(ctrl);
           url=attrs.childUrl;
           ctrl=attrs.ctrl;
           ctrlAs=attrs.ctrlAs;
         },
         this.controller = this.ctrl;
         this.controllerAs= this.ctrlAs;
         this.templateUrl =this.url;
    }

    static directiveFactory() {
       ChildDirective.instance = new ChildDirective();
       return ChildDirective.instance;
    }

}

 angular.module(module,[])
.directive('childDirective',ChildDirective.directiveFactory);

  export default module;
```

How to set the controller,controllerAs and templateUrl dynamically to the above directive?
Do you have any sugessions?

Comment: you are thinking that angular reads the dom first and then compiles the directive code... that's backwards. It has to know what to compile the dom with first

Comment: inject $controller and use it when you want?

Comment: controller can bind like this                                                this.controller='@';                                                        this.name='ctrlName'; but cannot bind the controllerAs dynamically